# claimsprincipalpermission is not verified for parent class if child class has already attribute

Tags: c#-4.0, claims-based-identity, role-base-authorization

I have a base base and derived classes like

```
[ClaimsPrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Resource = "Base",
                           Operation = "Create")]
public abstract class Base 
{
}

[ClaimsPrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Resource = "Derived",
                           Operation = "Create")]
public class Derived : Base
{
}
```

It never comes to authorization manager to check for base class if I am creating a derived class object.

```
public class AuthorisationManager : ClaimsAuthorizationManager
{
    public override bool CheckAccess(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        var resource = context.Resource.First().Value;
        var action = context.Action.First().Value;
        return context.Principal.HasClaim(resource, action);
    }
}
```

Any idea how can I implement that it should come to check for derived and base class both? Actually I want that if any one of them has permission, object should be allowed to create.

Answer (score 0):

Is that your real scenario? Or do you want to use that in the context of some app framework like ASP.NET?

But IIRC this is the behavior of CAS permissions - you could try the same with good old PrincipalPermission to see if the behavior wrt derivation is the same.

Comment: OK - I can repro the behavior. Have you tried PrincipalPermission in contrast?

Comment: I meant to compare the behavior. But yeah - seems like you can't use it for what you are trying to achieve.